No broker found - Kafka
I am trying to connect to kafka which is running locally on host machine, there are two servers which are connecting successfully to kafka(producer/subscriber) with .connect() method, but when I am trying to subscribe to topic or create the topic it is giving following errors:
Error from server1 (running locally):
{"level":"ERROR","timestamp":"2024-12-05T14:39:58.598Z","logger":"kafkajs","message":"[Connection] Response Metadata(key: 3, version: 6)","broker":"localhost:9092","clientId":"deploX_upload_service","error":"Replication-factor is invalid","correlationIError:Error: Something went wrong while subscribing to topic: logsKafkaJSProtocolError: Replication-factor is invalid
broker address: 'localhost:9092'
Error from server2 (running on docker):
KafkaJSNonRetriableError Caused by: KafkaJSBrokerNotFound: No brokers in the broker pool at BrokerPool.withBroker (/home/app/node_modules/kafkajs/src/cluster/brokerPool.js:270:13) ... 2 lines matching cause stack trace ... at async Object.listTopics (/home/app/node_modules/kafkajs/src/admin/index.js:103:31) { name: 'KafkaJSNumberOfRetriesExceeded',   retriable: false, helpUrl: undefined, retryCount: 5, retryTime: 8658, [cause]: KafkaJSBrokerNotFound: No brokers in the broker pool at BrokerPool.withBroker (/home/app/node_modules/kafkajs/src/cluster/brokerPl.js:270:13) at /home/app/node_modules/kafkajs/src/cluster/index.js:191:32 at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5) at async Object.listTopics (/home/app/node_modules/kafkajs/src/admin/index.js:103:31) { retriable: true, helpUrl: undefined, [cause]: undefined } }
broker address: 'host.docker.internal:9092'
kafka config server.properties:
listeners=PLAINTEXT://0.0.0.0:9092
advertised.listeners=PLAINTEXT://host.docker.internal:9092
